# help !!! what is the name of this tree?

Tags: identification, trees

Can someone help me find the name of this tree ?

thank you

[image: image 1]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! A few hints: 1) This seems to be a tree? 2) The proper tag is “identification” - and the [tag info](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) has more information on what a good identification question should provide. -> Could you please [edit] your post and add a few more details? I would also recommend the [tour] and the [help], especially [ask], for more information on how the site works.

Comment: Could you tell us where did you find such tree? To me it seems a Salix, but there are so many species.

Comment: What part of the world are you in (if you live where you saw this tree)?